# I'm having problems passing data from a textbox to another textbox in another form with this prexisting code

Tags: c#, winforms

I've read on how to pass a value from a textbox to a different textbox on another form, but I am having an issue figuring out how to pass the value with this method

```
private void editButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (this.editForm != null)
   {
      MessageBox.Show(@"An 'Edit Safety Report Item' form already exists." + Environment.NewLine +
      @"Please finish your edits already in progress before editing another 'Safety Report Item'.",
      @"Duplicate 'Edit Safety Report Item' form request", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
      return;
   }
   this.editForm = new MaintenanceForm(this.masterId);
   this.editForm.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(editForm_FormClosed);
   this.editButton.Enabled = false;
   this.editForm.Show(this);
}
```

This is called when the edit button is clicked from a form that is a report, and when its clicked it opens up form so I can edit the data, its passing all the data over to the edit form but one textbox is not being populated. So for a quick adjustment I find that it may be easier to just pass the value from the one textbox to the other on the edit form.

Thanks,

Comment: asked millions of times.

Comment: The issue doesn't seem to be in this code, it's likely in the other form.  This code isn't passing "all the data" to the next form.  It's only passing an ID value (`this.masterId`).  Presumably, the `MaintenanceForm` uses this identifier to fetch the current state of the record from the data source.  If it's not populating a value from that record in one of its controls, the error is wherever that happens.

Comment: The quick adjustments tend to become permanent curses.

Comment: @David, I think I understand what you are saying. The programmer who wrote this was using an array to pull the data from the database, I have tried changing the arrays by adding a new field to pass to a method but then I keep getting errors about no overloaded constructor expecting 8 parameters, then when I change that around I get a data error saying that its out of the array?. The maintenance form is the same one being used to add a new record and edit the added record. I'm not used to seeing it done this way using arrays to perform this.

Comment: @L.B, nice to see I was the lucky one to crack the million mark.

Comment: @Cwm: All I can do is speculate without seeing the code.  You're right that using arrays the way you describe is probably a bad idea.  Strongly-typed objects are preferred when pulling data from an underlying data store.  It's highly likely that there's a *lot* that can be considered "wrong" in this application, but fixing all of it is likely well outside of budget and scope for you.  If the text box needs to be populated by a data element on the record identified from that `masterId` though, then where you should be focusing is on that second form where it gets/uses the data for that ID.

Answer (score 1):

Don't derange that application. Someone wrote that `MaintenanceForm` object and obviously in it's constructor, it is using `this.masterId` to fill all fields of the MaintenanceForm - possibly after asking the model for the data behind masterId.

Look into the constructor of the `MaintenanceForm` and check, why the textfield is not filled. If the textfield  cannot be filled from the data available inside of the MaintenanceForm, either extend the constructor and/or add a property to MaintenanceForm that receives a string and puts it into the right place on the view.

Comment: I found the method that is receiving the mastered, so I overloaded it to take a string as well and passed the string with the mastered, and is throwing this error..Error 81 'SafetyManagementSystem.MaintenanceForm' does not contain a constructor that takes '1' arguments C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\New folder (3)\Chris\SafetyManagementSystem\SafetyManagementSystem\MaintenanceForm.cs 36 36 SafetyManagementSystem

Comment: and it brings me to this line right above the method...public MaintenanceForm() : this(0) { }

Comment: Maybe this is the time to add some source. Because I cannot really follow you. The compiler complains, that you have no constructor taking one argument, that means, you have removed `MaintenanceForm(int id)`. You removed it also, if you just added the String to the constructors signature. You need to fix the default constructor `MaintenanceForm()` to call your extendend constructor by setting it to `this(0, null)`. To be honest, I would ask someone who knows a little bit more about coding  to fix this.